# My app has no client ID?

Tags: android, unreal-4, google-play-services

So I'm using the Unreal Engine 4 to make a mobile game. I'm currently trying to set up the Google Play services so I can do Leaderboards, Acheivements and In-App Purchases but I'm struggling with the first right now.

You can see the behaviour in this [short video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uuK2fWnkJvQ).

It seems that it tries to contact the service then something goes wrong and it gives up. I made a logcat logfile from my phone while this was happening and this is what I got:

```
I/GamesNativeSDK(16078): Connecting to Google Play...

V/GamesNativeSDK(16078): Attached to JVM on thread main_dispatch

D/ChimeraCfgMgr(11916): Loading module com.google.android.gms.games from APK com.google.android.play.games

D/ChimeraModuleLdr(11916): Module APK com.google.android.play.games already loaded

D/ChimeraCfgMgr(11916): Loading module com.google.android.gms.games from APK com.google.android.play.games

D/ChimeraModuleLdr(11916): Module APK com.google.android.play.games already loaded

V/GamesNativeSDK(16078): Play Games callback indicates connection failure.

I/GamesNativeSDK(16078): UI interaction required to connect to Google Play.

D/UE4     (16078): [2015.10.26-19.31.29:804][  0]LogOnline:Warning: Async task 'Login' failed in 0.582350 seconds

E/SignInIntentService(11916): Access Not Configured. The API (Google Play Game Services API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.

E/SignInIntentService(11916): com.google.android.gms.games.server.error.GamesException

E/SignInIntentService(11916):  at com.google.android.gms.games.server.GamesServer.getResponseBlocking(GamesServer.java:164)

E/SignInIntentService(11916):  at com.google.android.gms.games.broker.PlayerAgent.getPlayerFromNetwork(PlayerAgent.java:1700)

E/SignInIntentService(11916):  at com.google.android.gms.games.broker.PlayerAgent.fetchPlayer(PlayerAgent.java:621)

E/SignInIntentService(11916):  at com.google.android.gms.games.broker.DataBroker.loadSelf(DataBroker.java:920)

E/SignInIntentService(11916):  at com.google.android.gms.games.service.PlayGamesSignInIntentService$LoadSelfOperation.executeInternal(PlayGamesSignInIntentService.java:402)

E/SignInIntentService(11916):  at com.google.android.gms.games.service.PlayGamesSignInIntentService$BaseOperation.execute(PlayGamesSignInIntentService.java:51)

E/SignInIntentService(11916):  at com.google.android.gms.games.service.PlayGamesSignInIntentService$OperationAdapter.execute(PlayGamesSignInIntentService.java:487)

E/SignInIntentService(11916):  at com.google.android.gms.chimera.BaseAsyncOperationService$OperationTask.run(BaseAsyncOperationService.java:179)

E/SignInIntentService(11916):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)

E/SignInIntentService(11916):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)

E/SignInIntentService(11916):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

E/LoadSelfFragment(16219): Unable to sign in - application does not have a registered client ID
```

I understand the error messages. But I don't understand why I get them. I tried to Deploy directly from the launcher as well as make a signed APK and install on my phone. It's the same result.

I looked around for a solution to this issue but I can't find any problems with the settings in my Developer Console nor anything missing. I'm a bit at a loss here and I'm aiming for a release in December 2015 so I need help. Epic Games had pretty much no documentation on the nodes provided to do this so all of this have been fumbling in the dark.

[image: First Part]

[image: Second Part]